# PowerShell: detecting errors in script functions

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What is the best way to detect if an error occurs in a script function?  I'm looking for a consistent way to indicate error/success status similar to $? (which only works on cmdlets, not script functions).

Given a particular function might return a value to be used by the caller, we can't indicate success by returning a boolean.  A function could use a [ref] parameter and set the value appropriately inside the function and check after the call, but this is more overhead than I'd like.  Is there something built-in to PowerShell that we can use?

The best I can come up with is:

1. In the function use Write-Error to 
   put ErrorRecord objects in the error 
   stream;
2. call the function with an
   ErrorVariable parameter;
3. check if the ErrorVariable parameter
   is not null after the call.

For example:

```
function MyFun {
  [CmdletBinding()]    # must be an advanced function or this 
  param ()             # will not work as ErrorVariable will not exist
  process {
    # code here....
    if ($SomeErrorCondition) {
      Write-Error -Message "Error occurred; details..."
      return
    }
    # more code here....
  }
}

# call the function
$Err = $null
MyFun -ErrorVariable Err
# this check would be similar to checking if $? -eq $false
if ($Err -ne $null) {
  "An error was detected"
  # handle error, log/email contents of $Err, etc.
}
```

Is there something better?  Is there a way of using $? in our script functions?  I'd rather not throw exceptions or ErrorRecord objects and have tons of try/catch blocks all over the place.  I'd also rather not use $Error as would require checking the count before making the function call as there could be other errors in there before the call - and I don't want to Clear() and lose them.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `try/catch`? It doesn't add much more than the `if` statement does; `try{}catch{}` vs. `if($err){}` is only a 2 char difference.

Comment: What I'd like to do is:
`foo -ev Err`
`if ($? -eq $false) { ReportError $Err }`
Wrapping every function call in try/catch is distracting to me; following every function call with a `if (...) { ReportError ... }` seems cleaner.  I would prefer to only wrap code in try/catch if I really can't catch/prevent a terminating error otherwise.

Comment: Think of `dir nodrivefound:\ ` 
ErrorRecords are put in the error stream and can be captured with 2> or -ErrorVariable, $? is $false so the error is easily detected but the script doesn't terminate and there's no try/catch.  I was hoping for something like that.

Answer (score 20):

> What is the best way to detect if an error occurs in a script function? I'm looking for a consistent way to indicate error/success status similar to $? (which only works on cmdlets, not script functions).

Error handling in PowerShell is a total mess. There are error records, script exceptions, .NET exceptions, `$?`, `$LASTEXITCODE`, `trap`s, `$Error` array (between scopes), and so on. And constructs to interact these elements with each other (such as `$ErrorActionPreference`). It is very difficult to get consistent when you have a morass like this; however, there is a way to achieve this goal.

The following observations must be made:

- `$?` is an underdocumented mystery. `$?` values from cmdlet calls do not propagate, it is a "read-only variable" (thus cannot be set by hand) and it is not clear on when *exactly* it gets set (what could possibly be an "execution status", term never used in PowerShell except on the description of `$?` in `about_Automatic_Variables`, is an enigma). Thankfully Bruce Payette has shed light on this: if you want to set `$?`, `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` is the only known way.
- If you want functions to set `$?` as cmdlets do, you must refrain from `Write-Error` and use `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` instead. `Write-Error` and `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` do the same thing, but the former does not set `$?` properly and the latter does. (Do not bother trying to find this documented somewhere. It is not.)
- If you want to handle .NET exceptions properly (as if they were non-terminating errors, leaving the decision of halting the entire execution up to the client code), you must `catch` and `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` them. You cannot leave them unprocessed, since they become non-terminating errors which do *not* respect `$ErrorActionPreference`. (Not documented either.)

In other words, the key to produce consistent error handling behavior is to use `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` whenever possible. It sets `$?`, respects `$ErrorActionPreference` (and thus `-ErrorAction`) and accepts `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord` objects produced from other cmdlets or a `catch` statement (in the `$_` variable).

The following examples will show how to use this method.

```
# Function which propagates an error from an internal cmdlet call,
# setting $? in the process.
function F1 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([String[]]$Path)

    # Run some cmdlet that might fail, quieting any error output.
    Convert-Path -Path:$Path -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    if (-not $?) {
        # Re-issue the last error in case of failure. This sets $?.
        # Note that the Global scope must be explicitly selected if the function is inside
        # a module. Selecting it otherwise also does not hurt.
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($Global:Error[0])
        return
    }

    # Additional processing.
    # ...
}


# Function which converts a .NET exception in a non-terminating error,
# respecting both $? and $ErrorPreference.
function F2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    try {
        [DateTime]"" # Throws a RuntimeException.
    }
    catch {
        # Write out the error record produced from the .NET exception.
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
        return
    }
}

# Function which issues an arbitrary error.
function F3 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    # Creates a new error record and writes it out.
    $PSCmdlet.WriteError((New-Object -TypeName:"Management.Automation.ErrorRecord"
        -ArgumentList:@(
            [Exception]"Some error happened",
            $null,
            [Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::NotSpecified,
            $null
        )
    ))

    # The cmdlet error propagation technique using Write-Error also works.
    Write-Error -Message:"Some error happened" -Category:NotSpecified -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    $PSCmdlet.WriteError($Global:Error[0])
}
```

As a last note, if you want to create terminating errors from .NET exceptions, do `try`/`catch` and re`throw` the exception caught.

Comment: I couldn't get @alek solution to work. Setting -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue just ignores the error. Could this be because MS have changed something in PS 5.1?

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are looking for a general mechanism to log any error occurring in a command called from a script. If so, [`trap`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=136586) is probably the most appropriate mechanism:

```powershell
Set-Alias ReportError Write-Host -Scope script  # placeholder for actual logging

trap {
  ReportError @"
Error in script $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName) :
$($_.Exception) $($_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage)
"@
  continue  # or use 'break' to stop script execution
}

function f( [int]$a, [switch]$err ) {
  "begin $a"
  if( $err ) { throw 'err' }
  "  end $a"
}

f 1
f 2 -err
f 3
```

Running this test script produces the following output, without requiring any modification to the called functions:

```
PS> ./test.ps1
begin 1
  end 1
begin 2
Error in script C:\Users\umami\t.ps1 :
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: err
At C:\Users\umami\t.ps1:13 char:21
+   if( $err ) { throw <<<<  'err' }
begin 3
  end 3
```

If script execution should stop after an error is reported, replace `continue` with `break` in the trap handler.

Comment: With the continue there, shouldn't there be a line saying `  end 2` in between the exception info and the line with `begin 3`? If not, why not?

Comment: @CodeJockey The `trap` is in the script, not in the function, so the `continue` is executing in the outer script after the function has exited.  If you move the `trap` block into the function, then you will get the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 4):

Two things come into mind: `Throw` (better than `Write-Error` in your example above), and `try..catch`

```
try
{
   #code here
}
catch
{
   if ($error[0].Exception -match "some particular error")
   {
       Write-Error "Oh No! You did it!"
   }
   else
   {
       Throw ("Ooops! " + $error[0].Exception)
   }
}
```

Imho, it is generally better to have the function itself to handle its errors as much as possible.

Comment: (Please ignore last comment)
I'd like to avoid throwing exceptions and try/catch blocks if possible.  Ideally the functions should act just like cmdlets - add ErrorRecords to the error stream that can be handled/filtered/ignored/etc. in many different ways, however the caller decides.  Throwing exceptions seems harsh as it terminates the current function and script execution unless explicitly caught.  I prefer the simple elegance of $?...

Comment: Cmdlets throw exceptions, which end up in the error stream.  So throwing exceptions would be acting just like Cmdlets.  Exceptions are the proper way to signal a failed command.

Comment: If you are going to rethrow an exception, use `throw $_` so you don't eat the stack trace or other valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a global variable $GLOBAL:variable_name. That variable will be in the scope of the script not just the function.

Looking at the code you may want to use trap (`Get-Help about_Trap`) as well - though $GLOBAL:variable_name would work with yours above. Here's a re-wreite of the code example - I've not tested this so it's more pseudo-code... :)

```
function MyFun {
  [CmdletBinding()]    # must be an advanced function or this 
  param ()             # will not work as ErrorVariable will not exist
  begin {
    trap {
      $GLOBAL:my_error_boolean = $true
      $GLOBAL:my_error_message = "Error Message?"

      return
    }
  }
  process {
    # more code here....
  }
}

# call the function
$GLOBAL:my_error_boolean = $false
MyFun 
# this check would be similar to checking if $? -eq $false
if ($GLOBAL:my_error_boolean) {
  "An error was detected"
  # handle error, log/email contents of $Err, etc.
}
```

HTH, Matt

Answer (score 0):

$? depends on if the function throw a terminating error or not.  If Write-Error is used, not Throw, $? is not set.  Many cmdlets don't set $? when they have an error, because that error is not a terminating error.

The easiest way to make your function set $? is to use -ErrorAction Stop.  This will stop the script when your function errors, and $? will be set.

Note this block of samples to see how $? works:

```
function foo([ParameteR()]$p) { Write-Error "problem" } 

foo 

$?

foo -errorAction Stop



$?

function foo() { throw "problem" } 

foo 

$?
```

Hope this helps

Comment: -ErrorAction Stop and throw do work - they set $? to $false - but the $? is never displayed afterward in your example as the script terminates because of the -ErrorAction Stop or throw.  If the foo call is wrapped in a try/catch it works but I was hoping to avoid having to wrap every function call in try/catch.  If you use try/catch there's no point in checking $? because if you are in the catch block, an error occurred.

Comment: What I'd like to do is below - it's clean but handles all errors:

`foo -ErrorVariable Err`
`if ($? -eq $false) { ReportError $Err }`
You can also pass the function name and params easily (if using splatting) to ReportError.

Answer (score 0):

Most of this made a lovely whooshing sound as it went right over my head... ಠ_ಠ

I am with  Dan. PS Logging is a complete mess and seems like it will more than double the size of the code I am writing...

Frankly, I would be happy if I could just capture console output directly to logs, warts and all...

The Try/Catch block is so ... so ... crappy, I can smell it and it has made my eyes turn brown.

The $? is very interesting, but you guys actually know what you are doing, as where I am at the point where I have realized I know nothing (last week I thought I knew at least something, but noooooo).

Why the %$#@%$ isn't there something like the 2> in cli ...

Ok so here is what I am trying to do (you've read this far, so why not?):

```
    Function MyFunc($Param1, $Param2){
Do{
  $Var = Get-Something | Select Name, MachineName, Status 
 $NotherVar = Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to Stop or Start or check the $Var (1 to Start, 2 to stop, 3 to check, 4 to continue)?" 
    If ($SetState -eq 1) 
     {
      Do Stuff
    }
    ElseIf ($Var -eq 2) 
       {
      Do Stuff
    }
    ElseIf ($Var -eq 3)
       {
      Do Stuff
    }
  }
    Until ($Var -eq 4)
Do other stuff
}
```

Did it work? Yes, fine... Log it and continue. No? Then catch the error, log it and continue the script...

I am tempted to just ask for user input, add-content and continue...

Incidentally, I did find a module PSLogging that seems like it would be pretty cool, but I am not sure how to get it working... The documentation is a bit Spartan. Seems like folks are getting it working without too much trouble, so I kinda feel like I am a corner sitting pointy hat kind of person...