# Propagate Execution Status

Tags: function, powershell, error-handling

## Description

How do you propagate the execution status ($?) in Powershell? For example, say a command inside of a function fails (so that `$?` is `$FALSE`). How do you make the function itself fail also (so that `$?` is `$FALSE`).

## Example

```
function gitpush() {
    git.exe push @Args
}

gitpush
Write-Output $?
```

Say `$?` is `$FALSE` after executing command `git.exe push @Args`. `$?` will be `$TRUE` after executing function `gitpush`. How do I make `$?` propagate so that it is `$FALSE` after executing function `gitpush`?

## Solution Attempts

The closest solution I've found is here: [PowerShell: detecting errors in script functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25979930/4257217)

Implementing that solution to the previous example would look like this:

```
function gitpush() {
    git.exe push @Args
    if (!$?) {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($Global:Error[0])
    }
}

gitpush
Write-Output $?
```

However, this does not work in this case because `$Global:Error[0]` is null:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:1
+ $PSCmdlet.WriteError($Global:Error[0])
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

---

`$?` is read-only, so it cannot be set explicitly:

```
function gitpush() {
    git.exe push @Args
    if (!$?) {
        $? = $FALSE
    }
}

gitpush
Write-Output $?
```

Output:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo" value of type "System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo" to type "System.Management.Automation.PSBoundParametersDictionary".
At line:4 char:1
+ gph; echo $?;
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

Comment: For external commands like `git.exe` you should check `$LastExitCode` rather than `$?` and then `throw` an exception if you want to propagate an error to the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @AnsgarWiechers, simply put a `Throw` statement inside your function

```
function gitpush() {
    git.exe push @Args
    if (!$LastExitCode) {
        Throw $Error
    }
}
```